# Change multidimensional array to a single dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have query which will return `id`, but instead of returning a single dimensional array it returns a multidimensional array

This is the query

```
$query_select_id= "SELECT `id` FROM `sub_pages` WHERE `page_id`=3";
$sub_category_id = mysqli_query($id_mysql, $query_select_id);
while($row=  mysqli_fetch_assoc($sub_category_id)){
    $sub_category_id_array[]=$row;
}
print_r($sub_category_id_array);
```

I am looking to change my array format from

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 13 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 14 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 15 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 16 ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 17 ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 18 ) )
```

To the following

```
Array ( [0] => 13 [1] => 14 [2] => 15 [3] => 16 [4] => 17 [5] => 18 )
```

Comment: Would be half the code with PDO [`fetchAll`](http://php.net/pdostatement.fetchAll)/[`fetchColumn`](http://php.net/pdostatement.fetchColumn) or [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query returns a row as an array, to just use a vlaue in that array change your line to:

```
 $sub_category_id_array[]=$row['id'];
```

Comment: @stacheldraht27 No problem, if it works for you could you select it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$single = arrary(); 
foreach($sub_cat as $val) {
  $single[] = $val['id'];
}
```

So, go through, append to array.

On second read through of your code, just change this line

```
 $sub_category_id_array[]=$row['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

For future googlers, if you want to extract a specific key from a multidimensional array and make an array out of it you can use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).

so in OP's case, he could have proceeded as follows to achieve his desired result.

```
$result_array = array_column($sub_category_id_array, 'id');
```

Answer (score -1):

multi_dimensional_array = [1,[9,[[[[[2]]]]]],[[[2],[12,[2]],[10]]] 
change to :
answer: [1, 9,2,2,12,2,10]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please use code blocks when you post code! :)